# Why do I get an error when trying to assign a value to a structure field?

Tags: c, structure

Consider the following structure

```c
typedef struct invInfo
{
    char chem_name[41];
    char chem_code[21];
    long quantity;
} invInfo;
```

And my main function:

```c
int main(){
    invInfo in,s1,s2;
    in.chem_name = "Kaki";
    in.chem_code = "K1";
    in.quantity = 8;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error when I try to compile:

```
error: assignment to expression with array type
```

Comment: You can't assign to arrays, only initialize them or copy to them. There even exists a special function to copy strings. Perhaps your text-book, tutorial or class have mentioned such a function?

Comment: [Searching Stack Overflow for that error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+assignment+to+expression+with+array+type) reveals many duplicate questions. Do not post without doing at least minimal investigation first.

Answer (score 0):

As Eric's comment points out, you can use structure initialization to initialize the character array with a string constant.

```c
invInfo in = {"Kaki", "K1", 8};
```

Or

```c
invInfo in = {.chem_name = "Kaki", .chem_code = "K1", .quantity = 8};
```

As Some programmer dude mentioned, you cannot assign a string constant to a character array after it's been initialized.

Comment: Arrays in structures can be initialized just as separate arrays can. OP could write `invInfo in = { "Kaki", "K1", 8 };` or `invInfo in = { .chem_name = "Kaki", .chem_code = "K1", .quantity = 8 };`.